# match_phrase query running mutiple in one query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to fetch some details that match "ListExperiences.Title" using a query from my elastic

```
{
   "size": 100,
   "query": {
       "match_phrase": {
                "ListExperiences.Title": "technical specialist"
            }
   },
   "_source":["skillstop"]
}
```

I was able to execute successfully and i got the required results.

```
{...
 "hits":[{
    ...
    "_source":{"skillstop": "government, active directory"
     } }       
 ]}
```

the length of hits = 1 as i made only query. 
But if I want to run for such five titles, eg: "support specialist", "technical expert", "technical specialist", "customer care respentative", I have to run the elasticsearch 5 times.

is there any way that I can run all at one time? (expecting i get length of hits = 5)

I tried like this

```
{
 "size": 100,
 "query": {
    "dis_max":{
        "queries":[
            {"match_phrase": {
                "ListExperiences.Title": "technical specialist"} },
            {"match_phrase": {
                "ListExperiences.Title": "technical expert"} }
        ]
    }
}
}
```

it is returning only the "technical expert" or what ever is the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If you want to launch an or query, you should try:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "should": [{
        "match_phrase": {
          "ListExperiences.Title": "technical specialist"
        }
      }, {
        "match_phrase": {
          "ListExperiences.Title": "technical expert"
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to make more than one query with only one POST request, you should use `multi_search` - doc [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html)

```
GET <your_index_name>/_msearch
{"query" : {"match_phrase" : {"ListExperiences.Title": "technical specialist"}}}
{"query" : {"match_phrase" : {"ListExperiences.Title": "technical expert"}}}
```